# Determine all download links in page, then download all files

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

I want to download all files in a site. All files have a link with text = "Download" and given click on it downloads each file.

The html of each file is like this:

```
<a abc-id="0" href="#" class="todown" nc="0">Download</a>
```

In XPath of each file the only value that changes is `tr` number like this:

```
    //*[@id='dwn']/div/table[1]/tbody[1]/tr[1]/td[3]/a
    //*[@id='dwn']/div/table[1]/tbody[1]/tr[2]/td[3]/a
    .
    .
    .
    //*[@id='dwn']/div/table[1]/tbody[1]/tr[100]/td[3]/a
```

My current code is below that works but I have several `time.sleep()` and `...click()` commands, one for each file:

```
import time
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Chrome("C:\webdrivers\chromedriver.exe")

driver.get ("http://www.examplesite.com/")
time.sleep(3)
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='dwn']/div/table[1]/tbody[1]/tr[1]/td[3]/a").click()
time.sleep(3)
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='dwn']/div/table[1]/tbody[1]/tr[2]/td[3]/a").click()
.
.
.
time.sleep(3)
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='dwn']/div/table[1]/tbody[1]/tr[100]/td[3]/a").click()
```

May someone help me in how to download all files in page with a kind of loop, since the number of files is not always the same.

Thanks in advance

Comment: use WebDriverWait instead of thread.sleep()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With respect to your given code, if only changing value is TR, then you can loop through all the TR tags by increasing it's loop counter value.

```
from time import sleep
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Chrome("C:\webdrivers\chromedriver.exe")

driver.get ("http://www.examplesite.com/")
time.sleep(3)
length_of_tr = 100
for i in range(1,length_of_tr):
    driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='dwn']/div/table[1]/tbody[1]/tr["+str(i)+"]/td[3]/a").click()
    sleep(3)
```

you can decide how you can define length of tr. You can get the length of tr tags dynamically while running the code or you can define a range inside the code as well.

Comment: don't use bare excepts, and using time.sleep() is bad practice.

Comment: @CoreyGoldberg Hi corey, the script loads home page, then click on a link and goes to another page within same website and takes a few seconds to open completely the other page. In this second page it takes some time to download each file and for both cases if I don´t use time.sleep() it doesn´t work. What could be used insted of time.sleep()?

Comment: @SurajitMitra Thanks for your answer, it seems to work, but the main issues is how to know how many links there are. In my example were 100 but that could change.

Comment: Can you try this one?  driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//*[@id='dwn']/div/table[1]/tbody[1]/tr") will give you the list of tr. From this you will get the length of available elements. Then use the length as length_of_tr value.

Comment: Thanks so much. It works pretty fine. Now I have another issue that I need to open  other question.

Answer (score 0):

findElements() method can be used to get all file links in a list.

```
List<WebElement> l=driver.findElements(By.linkText("Download"));
for(int i=0;i<l.size();i++)
{
l.get(i).click();
}
```

Try using this logic.

Comment: this isn't python